# Hiding a table row in custom Polymer element with named scopes

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm relatively new to Polymer and am trying to hide a table row in my custom element using the index of my named scope. It's not working at all, and I suspect I'm not on the right track. Could someone explain what I should be doing? Also, can {{index}} be used in element class names and IDs?

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="task-lists" attributes="name">
    <template repeat="{{t in tasks}}">
        <template repeat="{{t, tindex in tasks}}">
            <table>
                <tr id="{{tindex}}">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="task1" class="checkBox" value="None" name="check" />
                        <label for="task1"></label>
                        <span on-click="{{hideLink}}">{{t.name}}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </template>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('task-lists', {
            ready: function () {
                this.tasks = [
                    {name: 'Painting'},
                    {name: 'Cleaning'}
                ]
            },
            hideLink: function () {
                var row = document.getElementById("{{tindex}}");
                row.display = 'none';
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

First issue:

You can't access the model properties directly in the event handler. Take a look at [Event handling and data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/databinding.html#event-handling-and-data-binding) in the docs. You have to access the model associated with the template instance that created the event. Your event handler would then look something like this:

```
hidelink: function (e) {
  var tindex = e.target.templateInstance.model.tindex;
  ...
}
```

Second issue:

`document.getElementById` only searches elements in the main document (light DOM) but the element you are looking for is in your element's shadow DOM, so you have to use `this.shadowRoot.getElementById` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Tried implementing this but doesn't seem to actually hide the element and I get a very unusual error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/asterious/moffgce3/

Comment: Got it - `onclick` should be `on-click`